# Camel - Why the setProperty changes the header as well?

Tags: apache-camel

I've imagined, that setProperty change the header as well, and I don't know why.

```
<setProperty propertyName="A"><constant>AAA</constant></setProperty>
<log message="HA: ${headers.A}" />
<log message="PA: ${exchangeProperty[A]}" />
```

Both logs print AAA. Camel version 2.17.3, Spring version 4.3.2.RELEASE.

How should I use the setProperty?

Comment: Well print the headers before the setProperty. Are you sure there isn't a header with the name A already there?

Comment: Yes, I'm absolutely sure. This is the whole code:<br/>`
   <from uri="timer:MyTimer?repeatCount=1" />
   <log message="HA: ${headers.A}" />
   <setProperty propertyName="A">
    <constant>AAA</constant>
   </setProperty>
   <log message="HA: ${headers.A}" />
   <log message="PA: ${exchangeProperty[A]}" />
`<br/>And the result:<br/>`- HA: 
- HA: AAA
- PA: AAA`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by Claus Ibsen:

> This is working as Camel was designed with the header/property 
>   expressions in the DSL. 
>   A header lookup will fallback as property.

Source: [Simple message header.XXX and exchange property.XXX the same?](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Simple-message-header-XXX-and-exchange-property-XXX-the-same-td5752420.html)

Comment: I've not found that page, but found nothing in the docs about this "feature.". Thank you!